# Meaning of Keras model summary

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a machine translation model.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(english_vocab_size,512, input_length = 15))
    model.add(LSTM(512))
    model.add(RepeatVector(output_sequence_length))
    model.add(LSTM(512,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(french_vocab_size, activation='sigmoid')))
    print (model.summary())
```

When I print the model summary I get this:

[image]

I don't understand this. Why is it printing 10 layers whereas I have set only 5 in my code?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Its not printing 10 layers, you are printing it twice. `model.summary()` prints the summary already to terminal, so there is no need to call `print()` on it.

Comment: I did remove the print() on model.summary(). It is still printing it twice.

Comment: @AbhijitGhate Then maybe you are running that code two times, include your complete source code in the question.

Comment: Yes , it is executing two times. I'll try attach the source code.

Comment: @AbhijitGhate Then that is why its being printed twice. There is no issue.

Comment: The above architecture gave me an error at `embedding_38` layer saying input shape is wrong. If it is executing twice, it should have given me the error at `embedding_37` also. Isn't it so?

Comment: @AbhijitGhate That seems to be a different problem than the one in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168985/discussion-between-abhijit-ghate-and-matias-valdenegro).